# Visual Studio 2013 Query Builder vs MS SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I'm having a weird issue that I can't seem to figure out.

I've made a query in a Dataset in VS 2013 that returns values based on a quote number criteria.

My query from VS 2013 is:

```
SELECT        
   ID, quotenum, comprd, thrurd, dimension, titcomp, screenshot, notes
FROM            
   TableName
WHERE        
   (quotenum = @quotenum)
```

and the query from SQL Server Management Studios is:

```
SELECT 
   [ID]
   ,[quotenum]
   ,[comprd]
   ,[thrurd]
   ,[dimension]
   ,[titcomp]
   ,[screenshot]
   ,[notes]
FROM 
   [DBNAME].[dbo].[TableName]
WHERE
   quotenum = 'Q1206'
```

My issue is that I'm getting two different sets of results for one column.

The screenshot column is `varchar(MAX)` that stores a base64 string of an image. This column is the one that doesn't get all values returned in VS2013. Everything else matches perfectly.

Has anyone seen this or maybe have some sort of theory as to what might cause this?

Comment: Is the difference that the screenshot value is truncated in SSMS?  Check the max characters returned under Query-->Query Options-->Results.

Comment: Apologies, I edited the post just now because I noticed that I left out _where_ the issue was. SSMS is returning everything, it's VS2013 that isn't. This is the first time I've seen it do this in the numerous times I've done it in the project.